# Prove the correctness of an algorithm

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

Can someone help me prove the correctness of this algorithm:
[image]

I had to prove that $x_n + b\cdot y_n = a$ by induction, where $x_n$ and $y_n$ are the values of the variable x and y after the loop has iterated n times.

I have done that, but I am not sure how to prove the correctness of the algorithm.

Comment: You're assuming $a \ge 0$ and $b > 0$.

Comment: Yes, I guess so.

Comment: Try to characterize the different values of $x_n$ and $y_n$ when the algorithm completes. If it helps, you can also have a look at $x_{n+1}$ and $y_{n+1}$, and try to express why the algorithm didn't iterate $(n+1)$ times, but only $n$ times.

Comment: Is the algorithm supposed to produce the result of multiplying a by b? Or something else? Also, why is the algorithm just returning true or false instead of the result?

Comment: Yea it's supposed to determine if it's a multiple or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop invariant is: $x_n + by_n = a$

Base Case:
$\quad$Before the first iteration of the loop, $x_0 = a$ and $y_0 = 0$
$\quad x_0 + by_0 = a + b(0)=a$

Inductive Hypothesis:
$\quad$ Suppose $x_n + by_n = a$ is true for some $n \ge 0$

Inductive Step:
$\quad x_{n+1} + by_{n+1} = x_n - b + b(y_n +1)$
$\quad \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad= x_n + by_n$
$\quad \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad= a\quad$ (by inductive hypothesis)

Correctness:
$\quad$ Suppose the loop iterates $n$ times.
$\quad \;x_n + by_n = a$ is true by the inductive proof.

$\quad\;$If MUL(a, b) returns true, then $x_n = 0$ and $y_n = n$
$\quad\quad$ $x_n + by_n = a \Rightarrow bn = a \Rightarrow a$ is a multiple of $b$

$\quad\;$If MUL(a, b) returns false, then $x_n \ne 0$
$\quad\quad$ $x_n + by_n = a \Rightarrow bn \ne a\Rightarrow a$ is not a multiple of $b$

Comment: Thanks ily man!